# How to pass data from WebUserControl to a Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have WebUserControl which made of 3 DropDownLists (day/month/year). It has public property DateTime BirthDate. I create this WebUserControl  dynamically on Page (Page_Load). I want to be able to change data in loaded WebUserControl and save it with button on Page.

WebUserControl code:

```
public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList dd = new DropDownList();
    DropDownList dm = new DropDownList();
    DropDownList dy = new DropDownList();

    this.Controls.Add(dd);
    this.Controls.Add(dm);
    this.Controls.Add(dy);

    dd.Items.Add(new ListItem("day","0"));
    dm.Items.Add(new ListItem("month", "0"));
    dy.Items.Add(new ListItem("year", "0"));

    dd.Items.AddRange(GetNumericValues(1, 31).ToArray());
    dm.Items.AddRange(GetNumericValues(1, 12).ToArray());
    int yearNow = DateTime.Now.Year;
    dy.Items.AddRange(GetNumericValues(yearNow - 100, yearNow - 17).ToArray());

    dd.DataBind();
    dm.DataBind();
    dy.DataBind();

    if (BirthDate != DateTime.MinValue)
    {
        dd.SelectedValue = BirthDate.Day.ToString();
        dm.SelectedValue = BirthDate.Month.ToString();
        dy.SelectedValue = BirthDate.Year.ToString();
    }
    else
    {                
        dd.SelectedValue = "0";
        dm.SelectedValue = "0";
        dy.SelectedValue = "0";
    }


}

private List<ListItem> GetNumericValues(int from, int to)
{
    List<ListItem> n = new List<ListItem>();
    for (int i = from; i <= to; i++)
    {
        n.Add(new ListItem(i < 10 ? "0" + i.ToString() : i.ToString()));
    }
    return n;
}
```

Page code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        BirthDateWebUserControl bc = new BirthDateWebUserControl();
        PanelForm.Controls.Add(bc);
        ViewState["BirthDateWebUserControl"] = bc;
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BirthDateWebUserControl bc = (BirthDateWebUserControl)ViewState["BirthDateWebUserControl"];
    LabelResult.Text = bc.BirthDate.ToString("dd/MM/yy");
}
```

What i'm doing wrong ?

thanks

Comment: By "What I'm doing wrong?", what's happening that's not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working version of your control + page.

**User control**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class BirthDateWebUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    private readonly string ViewStateKey = "BirthDateWebUserControl_VSKEY";
    public DateTime BirthDate
    {
        get
        {
            int day = int.Parse(((DropDownList)this.FindControl("DayDropDown")).SelectedValue);
            int month = int.Parse(((DropDownList)this.FindControl("MonthDropDown")).SelectedValue);
            int year = int.Parse(((DropDownList)this.FindControl("YearDropDown")).SelectedValue);
            return new DateTime(year, month, day);
        }
        set
        {
            ((DropDownList)this.FindControl("DayDropDown")).SelectedValue = value.Day.ToString("00");
            ((DropDownList)this.FindControl("MonthDropDown")).SelectedValue = value.Month.ToString("00");
            ((DropDownList)this.FindControl("YearDropDown")).SelectedValue = value.Year.ToString("00");
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList dd = new DropDownList();
        dd.ID = "DayDropDown";
        DropDownList dm = new DropDownList();
        dm.ID = "MonthDropDown";
        DropDownList dy = new DropDownList();
        dy.ID = "YearDropDown";

        this.Controls.Add(dd);
        this.Controls.Add(dm);
        this.Controls.Add(dy);

        if (ViewState[ViewStateKey] == null)
        {

            dd.Items.Add(new ListItem("day", "0"));
            dm.Items.Add(new ListItem("month", "0"));
            dy.Items.Add(new ListItem("year", "0"));

            dd.Items.AddRange(GetNumericValues(1, 31).ToArray());
            dm.Items.AddRange(GetNumericValues(1, 12).ToArray());
            int yearNow = DateTime.Now.Year;
            dy.Items.AddRange(GetNumericValues(yearNow - 100, yearNow - 17).ToArray());

            dd.DataBind();
            dm.DataBind();
            dy.DataBind();

            ViewState[ViewStateKey] = true;
        }
    }

    private List<ListItem> GetNumericValues(int from, int to)
    {
        List<ListItem> n = new List<ListItem>();
        for (int i = from; i <= to; i++)
        {
            n.Add(new ListItem(i < 10 ? "0" + i.ToString() : i.ToString()));
        }
        return n;
    }
}
```

Sample page content:

```
<asp:Panel ID="PanelForm" runat="server">
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Label ID="LabelResult" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Click" />
```

Code behind for sample page:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BirthDateWebUserControl bc = new BirthDateWebUserControl();
    bc.ID = "bcInPanel";
    PanelForm.Controls.Add(bc);
}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        // init with some date in case not post back
        ((BirthDateWebUserControl)PanelForm.FindControl("bcInPanel")).BirthDate = new DateTime(1950, 4, 12);
    }
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var bc = (BirthDateWebUserControl)PanelForm.FindControl("bcInPanel");
    LabelResult.Text = bc.BirthDate.ToString("dd/MM/yy");
}
```

Some points to consider:

- When using dynamic controls, as suitable place to initialize them is `Page_Init`
- In a case like this (UserControl), initialize dynamically created sub controls in `Page_Init`
- Store necessary data needed to initialize the control in `ViewState`. Do not store the whole control itself.

And most importantly:

- **Question whether it makes sense to use dynamically created controls to begin with**. In this sample, the dropdowns in the user control could just as well have been statically declared. It would have made working with them **MUCH** easier (no need for FindControl + casting to correct type etc).

Comment: I will build control using reflection hence i use dynamic WebUserControl creation.

Comment: Ok. I will let my answer stand anyway in case someone else considering dynamic controls see it. Too many people are using dynamically created controls without any good reason.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically created controls must be created in Page PreInit or Init events, on every page postback.  ASP.NET will refresh the control's viewstate values between Init and Load events.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a `UserControl` like the following:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.ascx.cs" Inherits="YourApplication.Test" %>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" />
```

The goal is to be able get and set the value of the `DropDownList`, to do so we create a property of the `UserControl` that is able to do so.

```
public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public string Value
    {
        get { return ddl1.SelectedValue; }
        set { ddl1.SelectedValue = value; }
    }
}
```

Then we are able to use it as a property of the `UserControl` on other pages.

```
<uc:Test ID="ucTest" runat="server" Value="1" />
```

Or

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string theValue = ucTest.Value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if you want to pass data to user (FindControl because added dynamicly)

    you must use this

    public partial class UserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        public string Property
        {
            get { return dd.SelectedValue; }
            set { dd.SelectedValue = value; }
        }
    }


    When you create, affect UniqueId to your user control

    UserControl1 control = new UserControl1();
    control.UniqueId="Test";  
    add.....

    And find it in your page  with PreInit event before other events 

    UserControl1 control = (UserControl1)Page.FindControl("Test");
    control.Property = your value;



But if you want to pass data to your user control, this last must have this property with public modifier.
You can also pass with static forms as this example

<tagprefix:tagname id="" runat="server" Property="your value"/>
```

Comment: if you still have other problems do not hesitate , I worked long time on user controls